# PostgreSQL Partial DB backup

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a Postgres DB with more than 300 tables with compressed back up of size 10Gb and uncompressed data, almost 80GB which contains data for two years.

How can I get back of this db with less amount of data - may be for a day/month? Basically a DB back up file with all tables information with less amount of data.

Comment: It does not sound to me a really good idea, and not sure it is even possible at all. If you make a backup for a day, part of your relations possible saved, part of them is not, simply because updates were created later than their parent record. This can blow up foreign key constraints if the parent is from an earlier date. If size of a full backup is a problem, you can create a full backup first and then incremental backups later on to have all the information backed up.

Comment: @CsabaBenko Thanks for the comment. Yes your concern is reasonable. But my whole point is just to get a glimpse on the data rather than going for a full data.Since I have restriction on direct access to DB, thought of transferring the DB back up one time and load it in my PostgreSQL instance. There is no need for an incremental backup as I just need to load the data one time.